# JavaScript Parse signup not working "Empty Username"

Tags: javascript, html, parse-server

I've created a page for signing up with parse, this is my code where I left the initialization out intentionally:

```html
<input type="text" id="userInput" placeholder="Username" />
<input type="text" id="passInput" placeholder="Password" />
<input type="text" id="emailInput" placeholder="E-Mail" />
<input type="submit" onclick="signUp()" />

<script>
function signUp() { 
    var user = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    var pass = document.getElementById("passInput").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("emailInput").value;
    // Create a new instance of the user class
    var user = new Parse.User();
    user.set("username", user);
    user.set("password", pass);
    user.set("email", email);
    // other fields can be set just like with Parse.Object
  
    user.signUp().then(function(user) {
        console.log('User created successful with name: ' + user.get("username") + ' and email: ' + user.get("email"));
    }).catch(function(error){
        console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    });
}
</script>
```

but for some reason it returns with the Error that no username is entered, Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please share the actual error and your console logs?

Answer (score 1):

Variable **`user`** is declared on the below line to get and store the value from the userInput field.

```
var user = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
```

However, in the below line, you are overriding the above variable declaration.

```
 var user = new Parse.User();
```

now if you try a `console.log(user)` at this point, you will find that the variable **user** will not contain the value of the **`document.getElementById("userInput").value;`** but will contain the instance of **User**

That's why you will not get the right value when you try to run 
**`user.set("username", user);`**

use ES6 `let` while declaring variables, which will help you capture such issues while compiling and rectify it sooner.

For the current issue, just modifying the variable name should fix your problem.

```
let userInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value;

user.set("username", userInput );
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Here you set the var user :
    `var user = document.getElementById("userInput").value;`

then here you set the var user :
    `var user = new Parse.User();`

so when you do this : `user.set("username", user);`, you are actually passing in the `Parse.User` user variable

try this :

```
var userInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
var pass = document.getElementById("passInput").value;
var email = document.getElementById("emailInput").value;
// Create a new instance of the user class
var user = new Parse.User();
user.set("username", userInput );
```